# Using A Complete Office Word Editor In My Web Project

Tags: html, ms-word, ms-office, text-editor, rich-text-editor

We have a requirement in our web project to provide users create, edit and store their word documents in our application for their reporting purposes. I see there is already an online option from Microsoft Office [here](https://office.live.com/start/Word.aspx). But seems like it works in the Microsoft OneDrive cloud. I want to learn if there are any way to use only its Editor hosted by our own servers. I mean, the documents will not be saved to OneDrive but we will store them on our own servers and also the editor URL will be available from our servers too.

If this is not a possible option; what are your suggestions for a complete featured HTML based Word Editors? *(with page setup, page breaks, table editor and export as word document features and all)*

--

Answer (score 0):

You can use sharepoint to do this. You need the webapps feature